# Is it possible to stream MJPEG content over MPEG-DASH?

Tags: ffmpeg, esp32, live-streaming, mpeg-dash, mjpeg

I am trying to re-stream an MJPEG stream over dash using ffmpeg.

I have an ESP32 camera module that outputs an MJPEG livestream at 192.168.2.128:81/stream (Arduino code [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/ESP32/examples/Camera/CameraWebServer)).
I can open this stream directly in the browser and see the video in realtime, but the camera will only allow for a single client at a time while I am in need of a multi client solution.

#### What doesn't work

A solution I am currently trying to implement is to use a seperate server (Raspberry Pi) running apache and ffmpeg to re-stream the MJPEG content using DASH:

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://192.168.2.128:81/stream -strict -2 -an -c:v copy -b:v 2000k -f dash -window_size 4 -extra_window_size 0 -min_seg_duration 2000000 -remove_at_exit 1 /var/www/html/out.mpd
```

I get no errors when executing this command on the server.
I then use this [ffmpeg-dash.html](https://gist.github.com/CharlesHolbrow/3a6ac3882f4318909e0455c761ac7abe) to display the video in the browser.
This code unfortunately fails, in Firefox the console reports the error:

```
[72][Stream] No streams to play.
```

followed by:

```
Cannot play media. No decoders for requested formats: video/mp4;codecs="mp4v.6c";width="640";height="480"
```

#### What does work

What is puzzling me is that the above code works fine if I replace the MJPEG livestream url with a sample .mkv file, so if I use

```
ffmpeg -re -i /var/www/html/video.mkv -strict -2 -an -c:v copy -b:v 2000k -f dash -window_size 4 -extra_window_size 0 -min_seg_duration 2000000 -remove_at_exit 1 /var/www/html/out.mpd
```

I can view the livestreamed sample video (video.mkv) without problems using the previously mentioned ffmpeg-dash.html file.
Furthermore, it seems that ffmpeg can read the MJPEG livestream without problems, since

```
ffmpeg -t 10 -i http://192.168.2.128:81/stream -filter:v fps=15 -c:v flv test.flv
```

returns a 10 second clip of the livestream succesfully.

So to me it seems that the problem lies in how I combine the two. What am I missing? Is it even possible to stream MJPEG content over MPEG-DASH?
(I am new to this, sorry in advance for my ignorance)